# RSpec - Uninitialized variable outside of tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Sorry, I don't know how to word the title better, but here is a general idea of my test:

```
describe Model do
  let(:model) { FactoryGirl.create(:model) }
  subject { model }

  it { should be_valid }

  model.array_attribute.each do |attribute|
    context "description" do
      specify { attribute.should == 1 }
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that at the line `model.array_attribute.each do |attribute|`, I get an error of undefined local variable or method `model`. I know that the `let(:model)` is working because the validation (among other things) works fine. I suspect that the issue is because it's being called outside of any actual *test* (ie. `specify`, `it`, etc.).

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model` is unknown here because it's only evaluated inside the specs block context.

Do something like:

```
describe Model do
  def model
    FactoryGirl.create(:model)
  end

  subject { model }

  it { should be_valid }

  model.array_attribute.each do |attribute|
    context "description" do
      specify { attribute.should == 1 }
    end
  end
end
```

BTW, [there is a nice read here](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/).

Comment: I actually found a solution before reading this. Posted it as an answer. Can you take a look at it and let me know how our two answers compare and if yours might be a better solution than mine?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with the following code:

```
describe Model do
  let(:model) { FactoryGirl.create(:model) }
  subject { model }

  it { should be_valid }

  it "description" do
    model.array_attribute.each do |attribute|
      attribute.should == 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this works, of course. I supposed you wanted to have separated specs that's why I kept your logic.

Comment: BTW, my answer intended to let you understand why some vars are only visible in blocks and how simple ruby methods do the trick anywhere.