# RSpec passing variable or (let variable) to it block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Here's a code I have for a spec I wrote. I am trying to do an each for an array(payments), but when I try to add the let variable on top of the it block it's telling me that the variable or method does not exist. So I am assuming that the variable is not being called.

Can anyone take a look at how I should reogranize my spec so that I can do something like this:

```
payments.each do |p|
  it "updates the payment record of #{p.id} with a status of #{p.status}" do
    payments.each do |p|
      payment = Payment.find_by_id(p.id)
      payment_status = payment.status
      payment_status = p.status
      subject
      expect(Payment.find_by_id(p.id).status).to_not eq(payment_status)
    end
  end
end
```

Original spec code:

```
  describe "PATCH #submit" do
    subject { patch :pay, :payment => [payments] }
    context "when the submission is valid" do
      let(:payments) { [] }
      let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
      let(:member) { FactoryGirl.create(:member) }
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user }

      before :each do
        rand(2..4).times { payments << FactoryGirl.create(:payment, :payor => member, :merchant => user) }
        sign_in admin
      end

      it "updates the status of the payment" do
        p = payments.sample #get a random payment submitted
        payment = Payment.find_by_id(p.id)
        payment_status = payment.status
        subject
        p.reload
        expect(p.status).to_not eq(payment_status)
      end

      it "updates the record in the array" do
        payments.each do |p|
          payment = Payment.find_by_id(p.id)
          payment_status = payment.status
          payment_status = p.status
          subject
          expect(Payment.find_by_id(p.id).status).to_not eq(payment_status)
        end
     end
    end
  end
```

Stack trace:

```
kareem@kareem-VAIO:~/git/dns$ bundle exec rspec ./spec/controllers/payments_controller_spec.rb:320
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/kareem/git/dns/coverage. 256 / 673 LOC (38.04%) covered.
/home/kareem/git/dns/spec/controllers/payments_controller_spec.rb:320:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `payments' for #<Class:0x007f91b6085b70> (NameError)
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `module_exec'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `subclass'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:219:in `block in define_example_group_method'
  from /home/kareem/git/dns/spec/controllers/payments_controller_spec.rb:300:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `module_exec'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `subclass'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:219:in `block in define_example_group_method'
  from /home/kareem/git/dns/spec/controllers/payments_controller_spec.rb:298:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `module_exec'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `subclass'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:219:in `block in define_example_group_method'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:41:in `block in expose_example_group_alias'
  from /home/kareem/git/dns/spec/controllers/payments_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
  from /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why do you have an identical nested loop? `payments.each`? Also post the stacktrace

Comment: The first code is what I am attempting to do, but when I do so, I get the error which I just posed. The second code is the original 100% working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables defined by `let` outside of your specs.  If you really want to have it available, define a method on your spec and use it like that.

[This question seems similar, with a similar response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609340/rspec-uninitialized-variable-outside-of-tests).

Comment: Thanks, and apologies on posting something similar. I tried searching it first but couldn't find the expressive way to match my query. But the answer posted on that gives me clarification as well as your answer. Many thanks Sir.

Comment: No need to apologize you'd have to know the answer to find the right search. :)